# Make left and right panels to be fixed and not scrolled with the main page in xwiki

Tags: wiki, xwiki

How can i set xwiki look and feel when i have sidebars and panels in the sidebar to stay fixed. If the page is big and you try to scroll then the sidebars follow so you are using the content and if you have a navigation panel there you have again to scroll up to select something else.

I need to make the sidebars fixed